# Prove that exist $x\in \left\{ 1,...,14 \right\}$ such that $\sigma(x)=x$, where $\sigma\in S_{14}$ and $|\sigma|=28$?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

> Let $\sigma\in S_{14}$ which is an even permutation of the order of $28$.
>  Prove that exist $x\in \left\{ 1,...,14 \right\}$ such that $\sigma(x)=x$.

**My try:**

We know that the permutation order is equal to the least common multiple of cycles that make up a given permutation and $28=2\cdot2\cdot7$.

So $\sigma$ must be character $(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4)(b_1 b_2 ... b_7)$ - composition of row cycle $4$ and row cycle $7$
 because if $\sigma$ would be a character $(a_1
,a_2)(b_1b_2)(c_1...c_7)$ then $|\sigma|=2\cdot7=14$ which is contrary to the assumption.

That's why $4+7=11$ elements elements undergo nontrivial permutations and $14-11=3$ elements pass on to each other.

So $\sigma$ has a character:

$$\sigma=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5 & b_6 & b_7 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\ a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5 & b_6 & b_7 & b_1 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3\end{pmatrix}$$

Moreover we have information that $\sigma=(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4)(b_1 b_2 ... b_7)$ is composition an even number of transpositions.

However these are my only thoughts and I don't know what to do next to come to the thesis.

**EDIT:**

According to the remark from @EricTowers $\sigma$ can still have a character $(a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4)(b_1 b_2 ... b_7)(c_1c_2)$ then $$\sigma=\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & b_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5 & b_6 & b_7 & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\ a_2 & a_3 & a_4 & a_1 & b_2 & b_3 & b_4 & b_5 & b_6 & b_7 & b_1 & c_2 & c_1 & c_3\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $n_k$ be the number of $k$-cycles in the disjoint cycle decomposition of $\sigma$. Then

- $k \in \{1,2,4,7,14,28\}$
- $n_{28}=0$ because $28>14$
- $n_{14}=0$ because a $14$-cycle is not even
- $n_4 \ge 1$
- $n_7 \ge 1$
- $n_1 + 2n_2 + 4n_4 +7n_7 = 14$

The last equation has no solutions if $n_1=0$. Thus $n_1\ge1$, as required.

Actually, the only solutions are
$(n_1,n_2,n_4,n_7)=(1,1,1,1)$ and $(3,0,1,1)$.
However, since $\sigma$ is even, we must have $n_2+n_4$ even and so the only solution is $(n_1,n_2,n_4,n_7)=(1,1,1,1)$.

Comment: (+1) You've articulated this far better than my answer. I think we have the same approach; it's just that my understanding is perhaps a little too hazy. I could do with some feedback, @lhf, to improve it. Would you mind please providing me with some?

Answer (score 2):

It is not required that three elements are fixed.  Consider
$$  (1\ 2\ 3\ 4\ 5\ 6\ 7)(8\ 9\ 10\ 11)(12\ 13)(14)  \text{.}  $$

If the order of the cycle is $28$, there is at least a $7$-cycle and at least a $4$-cycle, as you have shown.  Any other cycle's length must divide $7$ or $4$.  How many ways can the three elements not in those two cycles be distributed among divisor-or-$7$ or divisor-of-$4$ cycles?

Comment: Thanks, I edited my post and I considered the case that you noticed

Answer (score 1):

You already have the prime factorisation of $28$. To get an element of order $28$, you need to partition $14$ into divisors of $28$ (namely, $1$, $2$, $4$, $7$, and $14$) so that their LCM is $28$.${}^\dagger$ So, what are the partitions of $14$ into those divisors, potentially including $1$, $4$, and $14$, such that the disjoint cycles of elements of $S_{14}$ form elements of order $28$ with cyclic decompositions composed of those divisors?

You'll find that you'll always need a $1$ in the cyclic decomposition. What does that imply?

You need to have at least one term of $7$ or $14$ in the partition. It should be obvious why you can't have a term $14$; can you have two terms of $7$? If the number of $7$s in the partition is odd, what does that say about the number of $1$s in the partition?${}^\dagger$

$\dagger$: I am thankful to @StevenStadnicki for the clarifying sentences provided in the comments.

Comment: I'm not lhf, but a few thoughts as I read this: you say 'potentially including 1, 4, and 14' but it's not really stated why those might be needed; I presume they're the 'don't forget that it's not just primes' divisors, but the way it's worded doesn't really provide a lot of guidance. I might phrase that as something like 'to get an element of order 28, you need to partition 14 into divisors of 28 (namely, 1, 2, 4, 7, and 14) so that their LCM is 28.'

Comment: Your second paragraph is pretty good, but you could add a quick note about _why_ you always need a 1 there - for instance, the parity argument: 'you need to have at least one  term of 7 or 14 in the partition. It should be obvious why you can't have a term 14; can you have two terms of 7? If the number of 7s in the partition is odd, what does that say about the number of 1s in the partition?' or something like that.

Comment: Thank you, @StevenStadnicki; I've included your feedback into the answer and have credited you.